# Is there a latest example of using mutex under boost 1.48.0?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, mutex

Most of the examples I've found on the web are outdated, using boost::mutex which I've failed to declare either including  or . Is there any clear example of how to use boost::mutex in ver 1.48.0? [The tutorials in Chapter 27 (Threads)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/thread.html) are extremely unclear and do not provide any code samples.

Comment: I don't remember having any problem with boost::mutex when updating from boost 1.34 to more recent versions. Could you give us more details the actual problem?

Comment: @BenC: actually I've now found the problem to be strange. Using boost::mutex can successfully compile except that there is an error hint in Eclipse saying "boost::mutex could not be resolved", but when I try to actually build the project it works smooth. No idea why it happens like this.

Comment: I have stopped using Eclipse years ago so I can't really help you on that. Sometimes the information given by the IDE can be misleading, but the most important part is that the compilation happens with no error. However, if you stumble on an error linked to boost::mutex during the compilation, feel free to share the error message with us.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check this example (`boost::mutex` usage is presented in `Resource::use()`):

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

class Resource
{
public:
    Resource(): i(0) {}

    void use()
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(guard);
        ++i;
    }

private:
    int i;
    boost::mutex guard;
};

void thread_func(Resource& resource)
{
    resource.use();
}

int main()
{
    Resource resource;
    boost::thread_group thread_group;
    thread_group.create_thread(boost::bind(thread_func, boost::ref(resource)));
    thread_group.create_thread(boost::bind(thread_func, boost::ref(resource)));
    thread_group.join_all();
    return 0;
}
```